# Express JS MongoDB forEach find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a big problem.
I want to iterate over collection a result set and for each set i want to find one result.

This looks like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var floors = [];
    var rooms = [];

    req.db.collection('floors').find().sort({_id: 1}).forEach(function(floor) {
        floors.push(floor);
    });

    req.db.collection('rooms').find().sort({_id: 1}).forEach(function(room) {
        req.db.collection('floors').findOne({_id: new ObjectID(room.floorId)}, function(error, floor) {
            room.floor = floor;
            rooms.push(room);
        });
    });

    res.render('rooms', { floors: floors, rooms: rooms });
});
```

The Problem is that the page will be rendered before the iteration is complete.
I tried to use async and promises, but i didn't get it to run.

Comment: its because res.render('rooms... is outside the callback. move it upwards between the two });

Comment: Thats not working, because then render will be called multiple times (for every 'for each'

Comment: which mongo driver do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to wait until all your queries are done before sending the rendering result. Unfortunately you don't use promises so this will get a bit messy.

It appears that you are using the native client and according to the docs there is a second callback that gets called when all iterations are done
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#forEach

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var floors = [];
  var rooms = [];

  function done(err){
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.render('rooms', { floors: floors, rooms: rooms });
  }

  function getRooms(err){
    if(err){
      return next(err);
    }
    req.db.collection('rooms').find().sort({_id: 1}).forEach(function(room) {
      // you already have all the floors, no need to hit the db again
      floors.find(floor => floor._id === room.floorId); // not sure about this 100% as _id could be an object
    }, done);
  }

  req.db.collection('floors').find().sort({_id: 1}).forEach(function(floor) {
    floors.push(floor);
  }, getRooms);

});
```

to be noted that this request will get quite heavy when your db grows.